# Foreman/Katello with ansible

Tags: ssl, certificate, ansible, foreman, katello

Im just going nuts with the ansible plugin for foreman/katello.

https://theforeman.org/plugins/foreman_ansible/1.x/index.html

I just installed as described.

When I run ansibl-playbook, I get the following error:

```
# ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/temp.yml
 [WARNING]: SSL verification of https://katello.domain.com disabled


PLAY [test the ansible] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [katello.domain.com]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
katello.domain.com : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

 [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_playbook_on_stats) in callback plugin (</usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/foreman.CallbackModule object at 0x2d2b750>): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:579)

 [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_playbook_on_stats) in callback plugin (</usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/foreman.CallbackModule object at 0x2d82ed0>): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:579)
```

Im using a officially signed certificate from comodo.

```
SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/katello.domain.com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/katello.domain.com.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/katello.domain.com-ca.crt"
```

And my callback-plugin configuration:

```
FOREMAN_URL = os.getenv('FOREMAN_URL', "https://katello.domain.com")
FOREMAN_SSL_CERT = (os.getenv('FOREMAN_SSL_CERT',
                              "/etc/pki/tls/certs/katello.domain.com.crt"),
                    os.getenv('FOREMAN_SSL_KEY',
                              "/etc/pki/tls/private/katello.domain.com.key"))
FOREMAN_SSL_VERIFY = os.getenv('FOREMAN_SSL_VERIFY', "0")
```

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

hello you can try this

```
FOREMAN_URL = os.getenv('FOREMAN_URL', "https://katello.domain.com")
# Substitute by a real SSL certificate and key if your Foreman uses HTTPS FOREMAN_SSL_CERT = (os.getenv('FOREMAN_SSL_CERT', "/etc/foreman/client_cert.pem"),
                    os.getenv('FOREMAN_SSL_KEY', "/etc/foreman/client_key.pem")) FOREMAN_SSL_VERIFY = os.getenv('FOREMAN_SSL_VERIFY', "1")
```

/etc/foreman/client_cert.pem & /etc/foreman/client_cert.pem are default sertificate